# Difference betwen UISearchController.updateSearchResults and UISearchbar.textDidChange

Tags: ios, swift, search

If I have a `UISearchController`, what is the difference between:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

        // Use searchText
}
```

and

```
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    // /Use searchText
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`updateSearchResults` is like a superset of `textDidChange`.

#### Similarities:

Both are called when a new text is entered in the searchBox, and when the text is cleared from the search text field

#### Differences

`updateSearchResults` gets triggered in 2 more cases:

- When the search bar becomes the first responder (equivalent to the `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` method found in `UISearchBarDelegate`
- In case there is a Cancel button linked to the searchController, then the method will be called to signal that the search bar is no longer a first responder